# Details about fallout nv savegames and steam (cloud?)

Tags: steam, fallout-new-vegas, steam-cloud

In order to clean up my `C /` Systemdrive a bit I figured out 800 MB of savegame files of my fallout new vegas game played steam.
After reading a bit about options for moving them somewhere else and let the game know it (there is no location setting option in the game) it looks like it's impossible without weird registry hacks, I don't want to start with.

So I just tried modifying the `fallout.ini` file, changing the following entry:

```
SLocalSavePath=Saves\
```

to another folder and moved the savegames away.

The file is readonly, so first I had to change that.

When restarting the game, all savegame files have been returned into the original directory on `C`.

Next time I tried it, I removed the readonly flag, modified the .ini file and set it to readonly afterwards, then during game start randomly 16 of 92 savegame files have been copied back to the original location on C. If I do not set the readonly flag back, nothing is copied and I can`t load a savegame within the game.

The file Fallout.ini is changed after starting the gamy no matter if you flag it readonly or not. the file `FalloutPrefs.ini` stays as I changed it if flagged readonly. I wonder why only 16 files are "downloaded" from the new location or from somewhere else?

So I modified the INI files in a way they are not able to find any .fos savegame files, because the path I entered does not exist. Nevertheless the 16 files are "downloaded" again. After all I am happe they are coming back, so I guess I could just delete them. But 1st it's only 16 and 2nd they are neither newest nor oldest just random... And so wonder from where so started a fiddler session to track internet activity.

I managed to catch online savegame download activity. it connects to `steamclouddub.blob.core.windows.net:443` and gets one file per connection.

I have reset everything and found out that restarting steam has an effect to the process. After that, now instead of 16 files, only 2 files are downloaded. It's a mess.

Now I wonder: Do I have to take care of the savegame files anyway, because they are maintained be steam anywhere in a cloud and returned to my and my current platform whenever I play? If so: how can I get rid of some of the savegames if I let's say would like to keep only some of them? Does anyone know the exact mechanism?

Comment: what happens if you set the ini file as read-only?

Comment: Please dont add everything you tried here in comments, edit your question and tell there what you've tried and noticed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main reason you have a mess is because steam was syncing 800 mb of data.  This takes a while to upload.

To clean them up, you'll have to let steam finish doing the sync, start the game, and, with the game running, delete and/or restore your save files, then shut down the game and let steam sync.